# Codeigniter SQL Query Like in a group by field

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter code that produces this query:

```
SELECT other_categories.id as main_id, other_categories.name as main_full_name,
category_type as policy_no, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(" ", 
other_cat_details.first_name, 
other_cat_details.middle_name, other_cat_details.last_name)) as 
other_full_name FROM
(`other_categories`) LEFT JOIN `other_category_details` ON
`other_category_details`.`other_category_id` = `other_categories`.`id` LEFT 
JOIN `users` as other_cat_details ON `other_cat_details`.`id` =
`other_category_details`.`user_id` WHERE `category_type` = '2' 
GROUP BY `main_id` ORDER BY `name` ASC LIMIT 10
```

Is there a way I can add another query where I can another query that will filter my data where `other_full_name` like variable `$name_entered`?

adding this before group by:

```
$this->db->like('other_full_name', $name);
```

Produces: Unknown column 'other_full_name' in 'where clause'

Please note that this is for wildcard search for a result that is a series of characters as what the query suggests. having clause would recognize other_full_name. I'm wondering if we can add 'like' to it.

Any help is highly appreciated. Please ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `having` clause:

```
having(other_full_name = $name)
```

In codeigniter, I think it would be:

```
$this->db->having('other_full_name like $name')
```

or some similar variant

Comment: this is a wildcard search, im wondering if instead of =, we can replace it with 'like' in having, would that be possible?